# How to know when a mozilla bug will be fixed?

Tags: firefox, thunderbird

This is not a technical, but an admin process question.
I am a victim of Mozilla bug 872869 (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=872869#c73), which I understand (by reading the bug at bugzilla) it has a fix/patch already.
How can I know whether and when it would be fixed in my Ubuntu distro to avoid me going ahead and installing a non-standard version of Thunderbird?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using ? If it is not resolved with apt-get update, then probably not . either try a firefox ppa (daily build) or compile from source.

Comment: The best way to know when is to file a bug on Launchpad (`ubuntu-bug thunderbird`). The devs then will close it when it gets pulled, or close it if they won't pull the fix.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy answer to this.

The theory is that Ubuntu will only pull upstream changes into packages when it fixes a major enough security issue, in which case it should be issued as a security update to your version of Ubuntu after a testing period (within a week or two).

Bugs that are unrelated to security usually won't be fixed in Ubuntu's current release.  The fixes will usually naturally be included when the next version of Ubuntu comes out, assuming the new version of Ubuntu includes a new version of the software in question.

Firefox, however, is a special case, in which Ubuntu often *will* pull in changes from upstream, even when not security fixes, in order to get new versions of Firefox into existing Ubuntu releases.  The schedule this happens on is unrelated to Firefox's own release schedule and can depend on different factors, and the version they pull from upstream may not be the latest Firefox - it may be a special long term release version.

Your options are:

- Put up with the bug until the next release of Ubuntu or the next time Ubuntu pulls in a new version of Firefox.
- Compile and install Firefox manually.
- Obtain Firefox from a PPA from someone who has compiled it manually for you.

Comment: Firefox is not too bad to compile, it takes some time as it is a large package. ppa are not difficult either - https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/firefox-next